# Assigning multiple values to a dictionary key- Python

Tags: python, dictionary

as the title indicates I am trying to assign two values to one key. I know that there are a few answers on this website out there but I am quite new to python and I don't really understand them. Therefore it would be great if you could explain why the answer is the answer. Anyway here is the code I am trying to execute

```
card = {'1 of hearts': '1', '2 of hearts': '2', 'ace of hearts':'1, 11'}
print(card['ace of hearts'])
```

As you may be able to see i am trying to create a simple blackjack game and so I want to assign both 1 and 11 to ace of hearts (not 1 or 11). However the code I have written above gives '1, 11'. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Aren't you getting what you asked for? Your key is string 'ace of hearts', your value is another string '1, 11', so what you see is what you get. I would propose to make value as list of ints. card = {'1 of hearts': [1], '2 of hearts': [2], 'ace of hearts':[1, 11]}

Comment: What kind of deck do you have that has a `1 of hearts` card?

Comment: Good point just realised that :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a dictionary, you can make the key an array.

```
card = {'1 of hearts': '1', '2 of hearts': '2', 'ace of hearts':["1", "11"]}
```

You can then access the first variable by using:

```
print(card['ace of hearts'][0])
```

You can then access the second variable by using:

```
print(card['ace of hearts'][1])
```

If you want to store the array in the key as integers, you should use:

```
card = {'1 of hearts': 1, '2 of hearts': 2, 'ace of hearts':[1, 11]}
```

Comment: @dawg has a good point about storing the card values as `int` instead of string

Answer (score 1):

Use a set or a list in the literal assignment:

```
card = {'1 of hearts': [1], '2 of hearts': [2], 'ace of hearts':[1, 11]}
```

You probably also want to use an integer vs a string, since you can use an int to add.

Answer (score 0):

When you print `card['ace of hearts']` you get a single string. To break it up and put it in a list you could split the elements by comma:

```
>>> print(card['ace of hearts'].split(', '))
['1', '11']
```

or it's better, as others have said, to use list from the start.